# SSIS in SQL 2014 running an Execute Process Task failing

Tags: sql-server, cmd, ssis, share, networkcredentials

Running a Cmd.exe inside an ETL Process Task and it's failing with Exit code 1.

If I run the command as the same user I'm running the SQL Agent job as outside of the ETL it's running fine and giving Exit code 0.

I've seen some DCOM errors in Event Viewer and Ive taken steps to give permissions to the user I'm running the ETL through the SQL Agent Job for.  However it's still failing.

Are there other things I should check about running a CMD command across servers as a specific user?

Comment: sounds like permissions

Comment: If not permissions, sometimes batch files and CMD can do unexpected things with return codes. If you can share your code and how it's being called in SSIS and how you're testing it interactively, it might shed some light on it. For example some command line tools return non zero even if they worked.

Comment: it's actually calling the command and I'm getting output in the Log files we have being generated from the 3rd party vendor.  The error coming out at the point of failure is   

 Error: An unexpected error occurred.

And from what I Can tell.. the error is when it's trying to connect to a different server from within the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to say this was a permission issue ultimately for it to write a file inside the Default folder.  It wasn't manifesting as such until I dumped out the Log a little more.  I had to make the user I was running the agent job to be a part of the Administrators group on the SSIS server to allow the process to work.